# JSDoc - how to check types for JavaScript

Tags: javascript, eclipse, validation, jshint, jsdoc

I am applying [JSDoc](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-type.html) annotations:

```
/**
 * @param {number} millis
 * @param {function} callback
 * */
function sleep(millis, callback) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        callback();
    }, millis);
}
```

Then what tool would tell there is an error for line below?

```
sleep('aaa', 'sdsdsd');
```

Is JSHint aware of JSDoc type annotations? How to enable such support in Eclipse?

Comment: As a complement I recommend using http://github.eclipsesource.com/jshint-eclipse/, it will give you JsHint warnings inside the js editor.

Comment: I would like to support this feature. See https://github.com/angelozerr/tern-lint/issues/32 it will work with Eclipse but with Emacs and Atom soon

Comment: I have created an issue to support that with tern-lint (which is used inside Eclipse with tern.java) https://github.com/angelozerr/tern-lint/issues/42 I will implement soon that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer, I'm the author of [tern.java](https://github.com/angelozerr/tern.java).

I suggest you that you [install tern.java 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT](https://github.com/angelozerr/tern.java/wiki/Installation-Update-Site). It provides the capability to validate your JavaScript files by using JSDoc annotations. Here a screenshot with the sample of this issue :

[image]

If you need improvement with JSDoc validation, please create issues [here](https://github.com/angelozerr/tern-lint/issues)

Comment: Hi Angelo, I have been doing for a year. You don't recognize me on SO? :-) Waiting for you to give Enide 2015 a try http://www.nodeclipse.org/enide/2015/

Answer (score 4):

jshint is not aware of jsdoc comments. You could however look at using [eslint](http://eslint.org/) and writing a plugin for it that would perform type checking on function calls. Depending on how your project is set up you might end up having to pre-parse your code to extract the comments into a rules file that your eslint rule would use.

Comment: Jason, @PaulVerest, do you know of any plugin that already does this, now in 2015?

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at https://github.com/yarax/typelint

It's an EsLint plugin that does type check for JSDoc comments, and in addition supports it's own extension to use Redux state or Swagger schemas (basically any JSON schema) for type check.

It helps not to write complex composite types from scratch and use existing data.

Comment: That looks like it only works with object properties defined in a schema (and as far as I can tell, it doesn't look like it processes `@typedef` objects).

Answer (score 0):

now VsCode can easily do that. there are 2 ways to activate vscode's typechecking based on jsDocs .

1. comment `// @ts-check` at the top of the file you want it to be checked.
2. to actiavete it for all files, create a file named `jsconfig.json` at the root of your project which contains the following: `{ "compilerOptions": { "checkJs":true } }`

now enjoy type errors!